# Equation for radiometric correction of transducer output (and what that even means)

Tags: homework

I'm a sophomore working on remote sensing for a Science Olympiad and I am trying to grasp radar. My level of physics knowledge is very basic and I'm struggling to properly understand this. From some googling I think that this formula is supposed to account for spectral distortion when measuring transducers, but that might be entirely wrong.

$$ V_{out}= \frac{P \cdot K \cdot V_{sa}}{V_{si}} $$
<sup>Found on [this site](https://www.fxsolver.com/browse/formulas/Ratiometric+Correction+of+Transducer+Output+%28+output+voltage+%29)</sup>

V<sub>out</sub> = Output voltage of the transducer (V)

P = Actual measured pressure (Pa)

K = Nominal transducer scale factor (given an ideal transducer supply voltage) (V/Pa)

V<sub>sa</sub> = Actual transducer supply voltage (V)

V<sub>si</sub> = Ideal transducer supply voltage (V)

I think my main struggle here is putting all the pieces together. I'd bet this is fairly simple to answer and I'm just not seeing something. My main goal here is just to understand what this could be used for (satellites, presumably) and how to apply it.

To clarify, this isn't actual homework, nor do I need a specific answer. I just want to better understand such arcane mysteries as multiplying across different units (volts v. pressure for instance) and, again, the use of this equation.

Comment: It was recommended on Physics that I go here, so I've posted it to this site as well.

Comment: Crossposted from https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/730908/2451

Comment: It would be good if you could delete the question on physics.SE

Comment: This has nothing to do with radar. Someone seems to have mixed up the word *ratiometric* (relating to ratios) with *radiometric* (relating to radiation). The equation is about ratiometric correction, not radiometric correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site you cite certainly doesn't have much information.  Your very best bet is to start by using a sensor that has a comprehensive data sheet, and then *reading that datasheet carefully*.  I'd like to say that everything will be there -- but sometimes sensor companies just expect you to know how their stuff works.

This isn't so much about ratiometric *correction*, as the fact that you have a ratiometric transducer that is (presumably) being sold as an absolute transducer.

You know what a ratio is; "ratio metric" just means that the transducer output is equal to some power that you supply (usually a voltage, but it could be anything) times the thing you want to measure.  If you regroup your transducer equation it makes more sense:
$$V_{out} = P \left (\frac{K}{V_{si}}\right) V_{sa}. \tag 1$$

To read the pressure, you do one of the following:

- Supply it with the rated voltage, use the manufacturer's number for \$K\$, and compute pressure from \$V_{out} = P K\$.  Use plain ol' algebra to solve for \$P\$: \$P = \frac{V_{out}}{K}\$.
- Supply it with a rock-steady voltage that's not \$V_{si}\$, and use (1), plugging in the values of \$V_{sa}\$.  Again, use algebra to solve for \$P\$.
- If you have an ADC with a reference input, supply the sensor *and* the ADC reference with the same voltage (assuming that there's a voltage that is good for both the ADC and the sensor).  Then do *more* algebra to find the relaionship between the ADC output number and \$P\$.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like the site just pulled the equation from who knows where. It looks to me like it has more to do with load cells with a wheatsone bridge. The tags on the bottom of the page have little to do with the equation and this most likely has nothing to do with radar.

You would use this to do some kind of pressure correction with relation to pressure (presumably on a load cell). I am not aware that radars use any kind of wheatstone bridges for remote sensing (they use antennas) and would be surprised if they did.

I also think some of those equation sites use bots to construct their information which could be where some of the confusion arises.

Comment: I suspect someone somewhere mixed up the words ratiometric and radiometric.